# ReactJS delay update in useState from axios response

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react js and I am having a hard time figuring out how to prevent delay updating of use state from axios response

Here's my code:

First, I declared countUsername as useState

```
const [countUsername, setUsername] = useState(0);
```

Second, I created arrow function checking if the username is still available

```
const checkUser = () => {
    RestaurantDataService.checkUsername(user.username)
      .then(response => {
        setUsername(response.data.length);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      })
  }
```

So, every time I check the value of countUsername, it has delay like if I trigger the button and run checkUser(), the latest response.data.length won't save.

Scenario if I console.log() countUseranme
I entered username1(not available), the value of countUsername is still 0 because it has default value of 0 then when I trigger the function once again, then that will just be the time that the value will be replaced.

```
const saveUser = () => {
  checkUser();
  console.log(countUsername);
}
```

Is there anything that I have forgot to consider? Thank you

Comment: there must be somthing casuing this ! coukd be api as well !!!! slow internet !!

Comment: When and how are you checking the value of countUsername?

Comment: @SiddharthSeth when triggering a function after I clicked the button

Comment: Without having seen the entire code, here is my opinion, since the checkUsername A
PI call and the setUsername call to update state are both asynchronous; any code immediately after invoking checkUser will not see any changes effected by this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.then` is not synchronous, it's more of a callback and will get called later when the api finishes. So your console log actually goes first most of the time before the state actually saves. That's not really something you control.

You can do an async / await and return the data if you need to use it right away before the state changes. And I believe the way state works is that it happens after the execution:
"[State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)" so you can't really control when to use it because you can't make it wait.

In my experience you use the data right away from the service and update the state or create a useEffect, i.g., useEffect(() => {}, [user]), to update the page with state.

```
const checkUser = async () => {
    try {
     return await RestaurantDataService.checkUsername(user.username);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

```
const saveUser = async () => {
  const user = await checkUser();
  // do whatever you want with user
  console.log(user);
}
```

Comment: I see. Thanks dude, it really help me. So the solution I have made was to not update the useState and instead, get the return response from the function with proper use of await and async. thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

usually there is a delay for every api call, so for that you can consider an state like below:

```
const [loading,toggleLoading] = useState(false)
```

beside that you can change arrow function to be async like below:

```
const checking = async ()=>{
toggleLoading(true);
const res = await  RestaurantDataService.checkUsername(user.username);
setUsername(response.data.length);
toggleLoading(false);
}
```

in the above function you can toggle loading state for spceifing checking state and disable button during that or shwoing spinner in it:

<button onClick={checking } disabled={loading}>Go

i hope this help

Comment: hello @kingofday, i really appreciate your help but it has the same result. I have added additional code when I trigger the button function, you can check it if you want.